# Browser - &nbsp; inserted in td causing space above nested table

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have the following markup (waaay simplified, but the same problem exists)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>table test</title>
</head>

<body>
<table style="border:2px blue solid; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;">
    <tr>
        <td >root table cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:2px green solid;">
        <table style="border:2px red solid; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;">
                <tr>
                    <td>some content</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="ruleDoc.html">some link</a></td>
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, there is a space above the nested table. Looking at the live markup with Chrome developer tools, this is above the nested table:

```
    &nbsp;
```

It's a non-breaking space with a carriage return after it that's causing the space. But in my markup it's not there. How can I make it go away?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into notepad, saved as an html file and opened in chrome. The extra &nbsp; doesnt show up. What are you developing in? If its wordpress, it tends to add extra content.

Comment: It's static html for now, later will be a ruby on rails site. I tested it in jsfiddle and couldn't see it there, but testing it locally on a browser it should show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There was a non-breaking space after a `</tr>` tag. It's not a regular space, because I can't recreate the problem by just typing a space after the tr tag. But I can cut the space, refresh the page and it goes away. Paste in the space, and it comes back.

Literally an invisible problem!